# Can I add a FK column of same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating the tables as per the sheet provided by my client . This is one of the table provided to me to create .

[image]

How can I add a FK parent.id of the same table?

I created a query like this

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
id varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
idsite varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES Calendar(id));
```

Obviously this query failed. I know this is not correct ? could you please help to make me understand that this is possible case ? I have never seen this kind of FK relationship before .

Comment: Yes, a table can reference itself with a foreign key constraint. The reason, however, your query failed is because the table `Calendar` has no column `Parentid`; if it did it likely would have succeeded.

Comment: Note, however, I *really* recommend giving your constraints explicit names. Errors like `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK__TestCalen__paren__7F586266"` are often not too helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentid inherits the column type varchar(64) from the 'id' column.  You could try it like this

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_Calendar;
go
create table dbo.test_Calendar (
id varchar(64) constraint pk_test_Calendar primary key not null,
idsite varchar(64) not null ,
parentid varchar(64) constraint fk_test_Calendar_id references dbo.test_Calendar(id));
```

Comment: Steve, I'm editing your answer removing the NOT NULL, since the father of all children has no father :-)

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I updated and removed the NOT NULL and added constraint names :)

Comment: "Constraint name", even better! :-)

Comment: @SteveC What is the concept of constraint fk_test_Calendar_id  ?

Comment: @Yogus it's a name assigned to the constraint.  As Larnu mentions in his comment in another post if there is an error due to a violation of the constraint the system assigned names, i.e. "FK__TestCalen__paren__7F586266" can be annoyingly cryptic.  Better to assign your own name according to a deterministic formula, like one which contains the table name.